# NameError in StaticPages#home

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, passenger, production

I'm getting the "NameError" after doing the following in routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get '/help',    to: 'static_pages/help'
  get '/about',   to: 'static_pages/about'
  get '/contact', to: 'static_pages/contact'
  get '/sigunup', to: 'users#new'

end
```

Can someone help me, please?  Thanks.

```
Showing /home/bdme551/bdme21/app/views/layouts/_header.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined local variable or method `help_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f7474f3d208>:0x007f747555c508>
Extracted source (around line #7):


      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home",   root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help",   help_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Log in", '#' %></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

StaticPagesController has the following:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end
  def help
  end
  def about
  end
  def contact
  end
end
```

Comment: What are you trying to fire when comes up that error? You're routes is fine. But if you are trying to fire `contact`, your controller name is typo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you haven't defined a name for your custom `GET` route. If you run `rake routes`, you should not find a `prefix` for any route except `root`.

You can add a name to a custom route with the `as` option.

```
get '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help', as: :help
```

Note that in your code you have `static_pages/help` as the value for `to` option.

It should be `static_pages#help`. `#` refers to instance method.

Now, if you try to run `rake routes`, you should find `help` as a prefix for `/help` route.

Also, fix the other route definitions by replacing `/` with `#`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the typo.  I went ahead and changed that in the routes.rb file.  I have updated the question.

Comment: When I run rake routes, I get the following message: ArgumentError: Missing :controller key on routes definition, please check your routes.